# javascript algorithm: solution not working

Tags: javascript

The problem is this one: I need to generate a function that:

"Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array. The arguments ["hello", "hey"] should return false, for instance, because the string "hello" does not contain a "y"."

I came up with this one, but it´s not working and I don´t understand why:

```
function mutation(arr) {
   var test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
   var target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
   for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
     if (target.indexOf(test[i]) >= 0){
       return true;
     }      
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning after the first successful check. You can change that to returning `false` at the first *unsuccessful* check:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (target.indexOf(test[i]) < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(['hello', 'hey']));
console.log(mutation(['hello', 'helo']));
```

Comment: Just wanted to post the exact same answer. You were faster by 7 seconds =D

Comment: Thank you. But why though? I don´t understand why the order matters so much here.

Comment: @EternalDoubter because as soon as you return, the for loop terminates. So you only check for `h` and then return true. You want to check *all* the letters.

Comment: But why does "false" keep the loop going and true ends it? Shouldn´t it go to "true" after the first "false" encounter?

Comment: Simply put, you don't want to return when found a match, you want to return when found a _not_ match.

Comment: @EternalDoubter it would terminate with `false` too, but in that case it would be the right answer (because we found a letter that was not in `target`). If `return false` was never executed, we know that the for loop must have checked all the letters and we therefore return `true` at the end.

Comment: How **not** to be a lifeguard:  1) Check the first kid in the pool.  2) Is the kid breathing?  3) If so then all children in the pool are breathing, you can take the rest of the day off.  4)  Oh you're still here?

Comment: Hahaha, I laughed out loud at the lifeguard thing. Thanks everyone, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
function mutation(arr){
var check = true;
arr[1].split('').forEach(x=>{
if(!arr[0].includes(x)){
check = false;
}
})
return check;
}
mutation(['hello','h']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function mutation(arr) {
   var test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
   var target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
   for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
     if (!target.includes(test[i])){
       return false;
     }      
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is modern, highly readable, functional approach to your problem, with no cycles at all. More readable version:

```
let testStrings = ['hello', 'hey']

function compare (arrayOfStrings) {
  let searchIn = [...arrayOfStrings[0]]
  let theseLetters = [...arrayOfStrings[1]]
  const condition = letter => searchIn.includes(letter)

  return theseLetters.every(condition)
}

console.log(compare(testStrings))
```

Or hipsters version:

```
let testStrings = ['hello', 'hey']

function compare (a) {
  let [i, t] = a.map(v => [...v])
  return t.every(l => i.includes(l))
}

console.log(compare(testStrings))
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting algorithm, trying to solve in a funcional ES6 way...

```js
const array1 = ['hello', 'ole'];
const array2 = ['hello', 'helloeloe']
const array3 = ['hello', 'hey']


const mutation = (array) => {
  const [target, test] = array.map(
    item => item.toLowerCase().split('')
  )
  return !test.filter(item => !target.includes(item)).length;
}

console.log(mutation(array1));
console.log(mutation(array2));
console.log(mutation(array3));
```